# AttributeError: Layer has no inbound nodes - occurred in TF >= 2.4 but works in TF < 2.4?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Here there is a reduced example of the code:

```py
class MyCustomLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_filters=64, kernel_size=3):
        keras.layers.Layer.__init__(self)
        self.conv_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=num_filters,
                                          kernel_size=kernel_size)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.conv_1(inputs)

x = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
my_custom_layer = MyCustomLayer()
y = my_custom_layer(x)
```

The following line works:

```
my_custom_layer.output
# Out: <KerasTensor: shape=(None, None, None, 64) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'my_custom_layer')>
```

However, this breaks in Tensorflow 2.4.1:

```
my_custom_layer.conv_1.output
```

with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-74d9fc3b4fbb> in <module>
----> 1 my_custom_layer.conv_1.output

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in output(self)
   2152     """
   2153     if not self._inbound_nodes:
-> 2154       raise AttributeError('Layer ' + self.name + ' has no inbound nodes.')
   2155     return self._get_node_attribute_at_index(0, 'output_tensors', 'output')
   2156 

AttributeError: Layer conv2d has no inbound nodes.
```

If I run the same code in Tensorflow 2.3.1 it works without any problem. I looked through the changelog, but I did not spot what could break it. What could be the reason?

---

GitHub Issue #48196: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48196

Answer (score 3):

I've also faced similar issue. Now I've also tested your code with `tf 2.0`, `2.1`, `2.2`, `2.3` in both CPU and GPU mode and it's working. But it **breaks** on `tf 2.4` and also `tf-nightly 2.6.0-dev20210330`. It seems like a **bug**. With `tf < 2.4`, the `my_custom_layer.conv_1.inbound_nodes` returns

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.node.Node at 0x7f751f301bd0>]
```

unlike empty `[]` in `tf > = 2.4`.

Comment: Thank you for checking it! Then, it is not a problem on my side then... Good to know.

Comment: I recommend raising an issue on Github.

Comment: @desa - it would be helpful to link this post in the github issue (and to link the issue in this post) so other users can keep track of the discussion

Comment: Here there is a link to the issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48196

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary fix to make it work (*only tested on TF2.4*), you can disable the use of KerasTensor with the following command:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor
keras_tensor.disable_keras_tensors()

# .... Rest of your code
```

Using your example, you can have access to inner component:

```py
my_custom_layer.conv_1.output 
# <tf.Tensor 'my_custom_layer_2/conv2d_2/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, None, None, 64) dtype=float32>
```